# Set up particular BCs for a block in an elasticity problem

Tags: boundary-conditions, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

Let's consider an incompressible block of Neo-Hookean material. Let the initial reference geometry be described by $B=[0,b] \times [0,b] \times [0,b]$. The professor gave me the following task:

> Set up the boundary conditions of your problem so that the lateral
> surfaces can move on a plane parallel to the $e_1 e_3$ plane. Since
> you have to work in the reference, use first Piola-Kirchhoff stress
> tensor $S$.

Of course there can be many possibilities. I was thinking to the case when the block is extended in the $e_1$ direction by a load factor of $\delta$.

I came up with the following B.Cs. Here $u(p) = x(p)-p$ is the displacement corresponding to a deformation map $x$

- $S_{22}=0$ so that I have no normal stress in the lateral faces with normal $e_2$.
- $e_3 \cdot S(-e_1) = e_2 \cdot S(e_1)=0$ so that I am constraining the block to do not move
- $e_2 \cdot S(e_1) = e_3 \cdot S(e_1)=0$ same as above, but on the the face with normal $e_1$
- $u_1(p)=\delta$ for $p \in \text{bottom face}$, i.e. displacement equal to $\delta$ in the $e_1$ direction.

Below there is an image of how I imagine the first Piola-Kirchhoff stresses for this problem.

[image]

Unfortunately, I am afraid that I loose the incompressibility in this way

Comment: Why not imposing only displacement boundary conditions?

Comment: That could be okay actually. I could impose that $u_1 = \delta$ on the orange face (i.e. the displacement in direction $e_1$ is $\delta$). Now I want to impose that the face with normal $-e_1$ is constrained to not move: I chould chose $u_1= 0$ there, right? @nicoguaro

Comment: Actually, according to what the question asks you don't need to impose any displacement different from 0. You could use rollers and that's it.

Comment: @nicoguaro what do you mean by "rollers"?

Comment: A roller is a constrain in the direction perpendicular to the plane. It allows points to move on the plane freely but not in the perpendicular direction.

Comment: @nicoguaro How can you impose such a condition? I've never seen them so far, but I'd love to see how one can impose this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126152/discussion-between-nicoguaro-and-bobinthebox).